# Simple authentification with passport.js turning into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm sure, I'm doing something wrong coz of my lack of experience with this technologies.
So here I'm trying to authenticate my user.

in server.js I have  the following :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//var configDB = require('./config/database.js');


require('./config/environement.js')(app, express);
require('./config/routes.client.js')(app);

//setting all modules routes
require('./api/oAuth/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port);
```

In environement.js :

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
    app.configure(function() {
        var path = require('path');
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var passport = require('passport');
        var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

        /*           je pense que ce code n'a rien a faire ici*/
        var User = require('./../models/user.js');



        passport.use(new LocalStrategy(

        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                username: username
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Incorrect username.'
                    });
                }
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Incorrect password.'
                    });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }));

        app.use(express.logger());
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../views')));
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.session({secret: 'm4B1teD4nsTaG0rgE'}));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());
        app.use(app.router);
        passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
        passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

        /*fin*/



        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/passport_local_mongoose');

        app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
        app.set('view engine', 'jade'); //extension of views



        console.log("config ok");



    });

    //development configuration
    app.configure('development', function() {
        app.use(express.errorHandler({
            dumpExceptions: true,
            showStack: true
        }));
    });

    //production configuration
    app.configure('production', function() {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

};
```

And finaly my api/oAuth/routes.js

```
var User = require('../../models/user.js');
var passport = require('passport');


module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
        res.render('../api/oAuth/views/register.page.jade');
    });

    //Route vers /login en get et post
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('../api/oAuth/views/login.page.jade');
    });

     app.post('/api/oAuth/login', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("post login = ok");
       passport.authenticate('local',function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
     });




    app.post('/api/oAuth/register', function(req, res) {
        User.register(
        new User({
            username: req.body.username
        }), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);

            }
            else {
                res.send("Success");

            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit : Added user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
    var passport = require('passport');

var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serializeUser");
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("deserializeUser");
  done(null, user);
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

When the app goes into passport.authenticate() it does a lot of thing then it return to passport.authenticate() in a loop way. When I use the custom callback I realize that passport.authenticate() is going smoothly but the problem seems to be in req.logIn() function. I don't know what to do in order to make this work, and I tried a lot. I feel like a blind man trying to drive a car :D.

Comment: A couple things that might be worth checkout out: I don't know if you have a route defined for `/users/<username>` though I'm not sure if you're code ever gets to that point?  Also, you may not be serializing the user correctly, not sure what occurs in `User.serializeUser()` or how you know _which_ user to serialize?  Here's some notes I took on configuring passport with express (3.0) which might be of use to you: https://gist.github.com/dylants/8030433

Comment: 1. for /users/<username> you are right (I'm hoping to get a "cannot get" error). 2. I updated my post so you can view user.js and maybe the issue lives here. 3. Ty I'll read those carefully. It seems way better that what I found.